# PHP - How to handle including content?

Tags: php

For a particular project, it does not require a huge MVC framework, so I am going back to how I used to write PHP applications:

```
header.php 
footer.php 

-- pages 
index.php
```

But, from using frameworks, such as Laravel with a templating engine `blade` I have got used to when creating a header.php to use (e.g.):

```
<html>
<head> 
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Then in all of the pages:

```
@section('content')

@stop
```

No, moving back to the old standard, I am having to do this:

In header:

```
if(function_exists("content"))
{
      content();

}
```

Then in all of the pages:

```
  function content()
  {
?>

TEST

<?php

}
?>
```

As you can see, this does not look appealing at all.

Does anyone know of an alternative way of doing something similar to what Blade does (without using blade)? Or of a way that makes the process look more easy to understand and a lot less messy?

Comment: I don't see the problem of using a framework even for small projects. If you don't want to bring the big guns, you can use **Laravel's** small brother **Lumen** or another micro-framework. https://lumen.laravel.com The advantages are huge than using plain php and trying to reinvent everything.

Comment: There are many "framework independent" templating engines which give you those features without requiring you to use frameworks. For the ***practical*** solution, just use one of them. E.g. Twig. This is still a valid question for how one can do such a thing from scratch, but it's also rather open-ended, since there are infinitely many possible implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't feel it's necessary to use an MVC Framework to build up the application it'd likely still be the best choice because there's so much already taken care of for you like the authentication and the security side of things which are massive chores to take care of properly on your own.

A full blown Laravel installation may well be a touch heavy weight and feel overbearing but there's always the Lumen framework which is basically a stripped out super lightweight version of Laravel for exactly this kind of circumstance where the full fat version is a bit heavy, you should check it out if you're already familiar with it's bigger brother it might be exactly what you need;
https://lumen.laravel.com/

A couple of other micro frameworks like Silex exist too which might be good for this project, but if you're already familiar with Laravel my advice would be get a Lumen install up and running, then you're off to the races working in a familiar environment that's still lightning fast and secure :)